# Call the function in Ag Grid react?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

```
 const handleKeyDown = (event, ID) => {
        if (event.key === "Delete") {
            //alert(name);
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: `http://10.194.45.62:9763/api/setCue?Idx=${ID}`,
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Access-control-allow-origin': '*'
                },
                auth: {
                    username: 'admin',
                    password: 'password'
                },

            }).then(response => {
                console.log("Delete Inside Axios");
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("Error In Post Data", error);
            });
            console.log("Delete Key Press", ID);

        }
    }
```

I want to call this function in ag grid table but not able to understand where i call this function in :

```
 <AgGridReact
                    ref={gridRef}
                    defaultColDef={{ flex: 1 }}
                    rowHeight={60}
                    getRowNodeId={getRowNodeId}
                    rowSelection={'multiple'}
                    rowData={comments}
                    // onRowClicked={(e) => console.log("row clicked", e.rowIndex)}
                    rowKey={(e) => {
                        if (e.key === "Delete") {
                            console.log("row 1clicked", e.rowIndex)
                        }
                    }}    
                >
```

I want to call this function(handleKeyDown) in ag grid table(AgGridReact) but not able to understand where i call this function

Answer (score 0):

you should handle `onCellKeyDown`:

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-pine-hoxxos?file=/src/App.js:841-854)

Comment: thanks for reply, but when i use event.key==="ctrl" && event.key ==="shift" && event.key  === "l" is not working

Comment: you can use event.ctrlKey, event.shiftKey and event.altKey to check if these keys are pressed alongside event.key